# Wikidata SPARQL query of COUNTRIES who were FORMER COLONIES of UNITED KINGDOM

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to display all the former colonies of the British Empire. I have just managed to retrieve a country which is currently a colony. I am trying to get my head around the query in order to embrace either *no longer a colony*, or *colony during a specific time period*.

```
SELECT ?countryLabel WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256, #Country
           wd:Q133156.       #Colony
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you shoukd start from bottom and check out example colonies you know first in Wikidata, find a possible path to British empire and then proceed.

Comment: for example, `?country wdt:P361          wd:Q8680. ` shown parts of British Empire - clearly, it won't cover all, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_evolution_of_the_British_Empire there are many many more. I doubt all are covered in Wikidata such that we can find them easily. Another triple pattern would be `?country wdt:P31 wd:Q223832 . ` - and so on and so forth ...